# laravel 5 /auth/login not found

Tags: php, laravel

I've made some change in `routes.php` and rest configuration is default. `routes.php` is as follows:

```
//Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Output of php artisan route:list is

```
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method                         | URI                                                   | Name | Action                                                     | Middleware |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD                       | /                                                     |      | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                  | auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getRegister       | guest      |
|        | POST                           | auth/register/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}  |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister      | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogin          | guest      |
|        | POST                           | auth/login/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postLogin         | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | auth/logout/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}    |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@getLogout         |            |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | auth/{_missing}                                       |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@missingMethod     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getEmail      | guest      |
|        | POST                           | password/email/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postEmail     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD                       | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@getReset      | guest      |
|        | POST                           | password/reset/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@postReset     | guest      |
|        | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | password/{_missing}                                   |      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController@missingMethod | guest      |
+--------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

When I access the site via `http://laravel/` I get

> The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.

but if I use `http://laravel/index.php/auth/login` it works without any error. What is wrong with my routing?

I am using WAMP on windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: I would highly recommend using Homestead. It comes with everything set up for Laravel.

Comment: That's true. But is there any way to make it work on WAMP

Comment: Have you enabled `mod_rewrite` on your WAMP?

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Found the solution. It was some configuration issue with Apache. Re installation of Apache solved the issue.

Comment: but what if someone is using nginx?

Answer (score 14):

In my project, I had to add the following instruction to Apache configuration:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/checkin>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: This AND mod_rewrite was my fix

Comment: I also had to do both.

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable mode_rewrite for apache.I solved this problem following this blog
http://www.kingpabel.com/apache-mod_rewrite/

Comment: I checked out the link, but I don't get it at all. Care explaining?

Comment: that's true! I had the same problem and I fixed with this

Comment: That's exactly what the problem was! Thanks.

Comment: And to do so use `a2enmod rewrite` and after that reload your apache server with `apache2 reload`.

Answer (score 5):

Apache mod_rewrite

```
//enable mod rewrite
a2enmod rewrite

//restart apache
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

Without apache, You can test it with `php artisan serve`. Before you need to do some changes in .env, change `APP_ENV` to local. then browse auth\login,
check the error. In my case the error is : PDO not found.
Hope this might help.

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

The extra comma at the end of your array may cause something?

I'm having the same issue, but that comma is something I saw right away

Comment: Extra commas are ignored in array declarations in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a vendor package that has its own routes that conflict with yours.

If you have unexplained routes showing up when you run artisan route:list, they may belong to a vendor package that you recently added. For us, it was "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel".

The following code was found in "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel/src/app/Providers/AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider.php"

```
private function registerRoutes()
{

    Route::controller(
        'auth', $this->getAppNamespace() . 'Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController' ,
        [ 'getLogin' => 'auth.login',
          'getLogout' => 'auth.logout',
          'getRegister' => 'auth.register'
        ]);
    Route::controller(
        'password' , $this->getAppNamespace() . 'Http\Controllers\Auth\PasswordController',
        [ 'getReset' => 'auth.reset',] );

    Route::get('/home', ['as' => 'home','middleware' => 'auth', function () {
        return view('home');
    }]);

}
```

I guess that's why the "{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/" appears (I think this route pattern is added when Route::controller is used by the vendor).