# Laravel 5.1 /auth/login not found on Apache + Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I am getting exactly the same issue as [laravel 5 /auth/login not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154016/laravel-5-auth-login-not-found) . The only difference is that he's using WAMP, and I am using Apache + Ubuntu 14.

When I access http://example.com/index.php/auth/login , the webpage shows perfectly. But http://example.com/auth/login will return this error

> The requested URL /auth/login was not found on this server.

I tried both enabling mode_rewrite for Apache, and reinstalled Apache, as suggested in [laravel 5 /auth/login not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154016/laravel-5-auth-login-not-found). Neither way worked.

Comment: did you mean mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct `.htaccess` file, say for example you have your installation in `/var/www/html/myapp`, you should have an `.htaccess` file inside the **public** directory (`/var/www/html/myapp/public`) that reads:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myapp/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, is the Apache document root configured properly?

open up the terminal, run `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and put these lines int he config file to map the default root to the *myapp/public* folder :

```
Alias /myapp /var/www/html/myapp/public/
<Directory "/var/www/html/myapp/public">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

and then restarts Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Mod rewrite should be enabled, of course:

```
a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You should now be able to access your site at `http://localhost/myapp`

Comment: I'd emphasize `AllowOverride All`.. it's likely the root cause as the default install actually has AllowOverride None on the /var/www folder, you may need to change this in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Comment: Wonderful @evandentremont . Your suggestion works like a charm! Thanks to both of you for your kind help!